# Is there a size limit when generating an excel document out of a web page using Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a size limit when generating an excel document out of a web page using Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Answer (score 1):

By default with buffering turned on IIS6 will limit the output to 4MB (see [KB925764](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925764)), this can be increased by turning off buffering (and assuming you use multiple calls to write) or by tweaking the [AspBufferingLimit](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ea7e9c3f-d0c8-4e5c-8965-0d0429a3b8f1.mspx?mfr=true) Metabase value.